# Play Framework 2 displaying an image from a database or external resource

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, multipart

I am having real problems displaying an image I retrieved from an external store, in this case S3 but could easily be a database.

My question is how to display images that are not on the file system, i.e they are files/images in an object. I am using Play 2.1.1

View

> ```
>     @for(image <- receipt.imageIds){
>         <h4>@image.getId</h4>
>         <h3><img src="@controllers.Application.getImage(image.getId)" /></h3>
>     }
> ```

routes

```
GET         /receipt/image/:id      controllers.Application.getImage(id:String)
```

Controller (I have tried a number options here but this is one others seem to use)

```
public static Result getImage(final String id) {
try {
    ImageId image = AWS_S3_SERVICE.getImage(id);
    return ok(extractBytes(image.getImage())).as("image/jpeg");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return ok();
```

}

If I look at the generated output for the image that is not displaying this is what I see:

```
<img src="SimpleResult(200, Map(Content-Type -&gt; image/jpeg))">
```

Answer (score 2):

You are wasting lot of your own resources this way as you need to transfer file from storage to application, then rewrite it to output and finally send to the client. Each of these operations generates some costs and are redundant.

Instead you should use a direct link to file in `src` attribute, and additionally consider caching bucket's filelist on local DB so you won't need to ask S3 everytime for the paths...

it could be something like:

```
<img src="@utils.MyS3.getImagePath(image.getId)" />
```

Where `getImagePath` method returns just String like `http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.jpg` resolved from your DB/cache by id.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have just been testing out strategies on image storing as I don't want to store them in the database. I thought s3 would be a cheaper option as I intend to run the app on AWS. I will try your suggestion but I may also revert to storing on the file system with a backup in S3 or perhaps Dynamo db

Answer (score 1):

You spend ages trying to solve a problem, ask a question and then solve it a few minutes later.

I made two changes, one to the routes and one to the controller.

routes

```
<h3><img src="@controllers.Application.getImage(image.getId)" /></h3>
changed to 
<h3><img src="@routes.Application.getImage(image.getId)" /></h3>
```

controller

```
    public static Result getImage(final String id) {
      try {
        ImageId imageId = AWS_S3_SERVICE.getImage(id);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageId.image);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);

        return ok(baos.toByteArray()).as("image/jpg");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      return ok();
    }
```